# Multiple awks from one line

Tags: bash, awk

I am getting output from access logs to view hit counts, IP address, and user agent. The output isn't working because it's not capturing everything I need in the user agent string.

Example output:

```
Getting access logs from /var/log/apache2/my.access.log ...

Sorting unique IPs...

COUNT   IP Address | User Agent String

15165 xx.xxx.xxx.xx | "Mozilla/5.0 <--- Need everything between quotes
10704 xx.xxx.xxx.xx | "Mozilla/5.0      not just this portion
 9915 xx.xxx.xxx.xx | "Mozilla/5.0
 8240 xx.xxx.xxx.xx | "Mozilla/5.0
 7770 xx.xxx.xxx.xx | "Mozilla/5.0
 7266 xx.xxx.xxx.xx | "Mozilla/5.0
```

The line that gets this info is:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/my.access.log | awk '{print $11 " | " $24 " " $25 " " $26}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -30
```

I understand that the portion with $24 " " $25 " " $26 can actually be cleaned up with

```
awk -F\" '{ print $6 }'
```

My question is how can I add both of them into a single line, if possible?

Example raw output of log file (with some text altered):

```
[2018-10-10 10:11:22 (Wed)] | <servername> | R:<servername> | www.<thewebsite>.com | xxx.xxx.xx.xxx |"GET /script/that/was/accessed HTTP/1.1" | 200 | 1430 | 8104 | "https://www.<thewebsite>.com" | "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

I need that last section starting with "Mozilla/5.0 all the way to the other quotation mark, but in the same line as the other awk.

Comment: Could you please add sample of output too in your posts and let us know?

Comment: Which output? The output I showed, or something else?

Comment: The output of the logfile (or a small portion of it) in order to see what the input of awk is.

Comment: I think the exact output is required, so only requested you to paste the sample output. It is not clear from your shown one.

Comment: Edited question with raw output.

Comment: Can't you simply tell awk that the separator is a pipe between spaces (`-F' | '`) and then take the 5th (IP-address) and 11th (Modzilla stuff) fields? However, there seems to be no space after the pipe that follows the IP-address

Comment: @RobertKock That did it!

Comment: If you would like me to accept it as the answer, I'll gladly do so if you post it.